# When extending SurfaceView unable to access getChildCount() method?

Tags: android

```
public class CustomView extends SurfaceView {

 @Override
 protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        int itemWidth = (r - l) / getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < this.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View v = getChildAt(i);
            v.layout(itemWidth * i, 0, (i + 1) * itemWidth, b - t);
        }
    }
   }
```

In the above overriden method getChildCount() and getChildAt(i) throws no such method found.

Comment: It makes me wonder why you would need it. SurfaceView is not a ViewGroup. It can't have any child Views. You will find that it therefore hasn't even got addView() methods. How are you adding subviews in the first place?

Comment: I need to run viewgroup onDraw method in seperate thread.But as you said SurfaceView is not a ViewGroup,can you tell me any alternate way to run viewgroup draw on seperate thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct. `SurfaceView` extends View not ViewGroup. `getChildCount()`  and `getChildAt(i)` are methods of `ViewGroup`